# Proving that in an homogeneous DTMC $i\leftrightarrow j$ and $j$ is recurrent $\implies f_{ij}=1$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm struggling to understand the proof of the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $\big\{\mathsf X\big\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an homogeneous DTMC, P its transition matrix and $\mathsf S$ its states space; let $i,j\in\mathcal S\mid i \leftrightarrow j$, then $f_{ij} = 1$

**Proof:** Let $m\in\mathbb N\;\lvert\; P^{(m)}_{ji} > 0$. Then

$$1 = f_{jj} = \mathbb P\big( \mathsf X_n = j \text{ for infinitely many } n\mid \mathsf X_0 = j \big) \\= \mathbb P\big( \mathsf X_n = j \text{ for some } n > m+1 \mid \mathsf X_0 = j \big) = \cdots$$

And so on, I won't report the remaining part cause this one right here is the only one giving me a bad headache.

Now, why is the third equality true? I mean, to me the events in the probability argument sound totally different. I saw alternative proves involving renewal processes but we didn't study them in our class and aren't part of our program, I need to understand this one right here.

**EDIT:** Supposedly the two arguments should be equivalent, i.e.

$$\mathsf X_n = j \text{ for infinitely many } n \iff \mathsf X_n = j \text{ for some } n > m+1$$

The "$\implies$" part is obvious, but I can't see why the "$\impliedby$" holds.

We saw and proved a theorem asserting that if a state $k\in\mathsf S$ is recurrent then paths starting in $k$ are a.c visiting $k$ at least once ($f_{kk} = 1$) and then if $k$ is recurrent the paths starting in $k$ return a.c. infinitely many times in $k$, may this have something to deal with it?

Comment: I think there is something slightly amiss because after the second equality there is no more $i$. Presumably you want $X_0=i$?

Comment: @lan: You're indeed correct, it has to be $1 = f_{jj}$, I'll edit that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\F{\mathscr{F}}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$The property used in the equality is actually:\begin{gather*}
P(X_n = j \text{ for infinitely many } n \mid X_0 = j) = 1\\
\Longleftrightarrow P(X_n = j \text{ for some } n > m + 1 \mid X_0 = j) = 1.
\end{gather*}
For $\Longrightarrow$, it is obvious by$$
\{X_n = j \text{ for infinitely many } n\} \subseteq \{X_n = j \text{ for some } n > m + 1\}.
$$
For $\Longleftarrow$, define$$
τ_0 = 0, \quad τ_{n + 1} = \inf\{k > τ_n + m + 1 \mid X_k = j\}, \quad \forall n \geqslant 0
$$
then$$
\{X_n = j \text{ for infinitely many } n\} = \bigcap_{n = 1}^∞ \{τ_n < ∞\} = \lim_{n → ∞} \bigcap_{k = 1}^n \{τ_k < ∞\}.
$$
So it suffices to prove by induction on $n$ that$$
P(τ_1 < ∞, \cdots, τ_n < ∞ \mid X_0 = j) = 1. \quad \forall n \geqslant 1
$$
For $n = 1$,$$
P(τ_1 < ∞ \mid X_0 = j) = P(X_n = j \text{ for some } n > m + 1 \mid X_0 = j) = 1.
$$
Now assume that it holds for $n$. Denote $A_k = \{τ_1 < k - m - 1, \cdots, τ_{n - 1} < k - m - 1\}$ for $k \geqslant m + 2$, then$$
\{τ_1 < ∞, \cdots, τ_n < ∞\} = \bigcup_{k = m + 2}^∞ (A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\})
$$
and\begin{align*}
&\peq P(τ_1 < ∞, \cdots, τ_n < ∞, τ_{n + 1} < ∞ \mid X_0 = j)\\
&= \sum_{k = m + 2}^∞ P(A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \cap  \{τ_{n + 1} < ∞\} \mid X_0 = j)\\
&= \sum_{k = m + 2}^∞ \sum_{l = k + m + 2}^∞ P(A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \cap \{τ_{n + 1} = l\} \mid X_0 = j). \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Note that $\{τ_n = k\} \subseteq \{X_k = j\}$, so\begin{align*}
&\peq P(A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \cap \{τ_{n + 1} = l\} \mid X_0 = j)\\
&= P(A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \cap \{X_k = j\} \cap \{τ_{n + 1} = l\} \mid X_0 = j)\\
&= P(A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \cap \{X_k = j\} \mid X_0 = j)\\
&\peq · P(τ_{n + 1} = l \mid A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \cap \{X_k = j\}).
\end{align*}
By the Markov property,\begin{align*}
&\peq P(τ_{n + 1} = l \mid A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \cap \{X_k = j\}) = P(τ_{n + 1} = l \mid X_k = j)\\
&= P(X_{k + 1} ≠ j, \cdots, X_{l - 1} ≠ j, X_l = j \mid X_k = j)\\
&= P(X_1 ≠ j, \cdots, X_{l - k - 1} ≠ j, X_{l - k} = j \mid X_0 = j)\\
&= P(τ_1 = l - k \mid X_0 = j),
\end{align*}
combining with$$
P(A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \cap \{X_k = j\} \mid X_0 = j) = P(A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \mid X_0 = j)
$$
and the induction hypothesis yields\begin{align*}
(1) &= \sum_{k = m + 2}^∞ \sum_{l = k + m + 2}^∞ P(A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \mid X_0 = j) P(τ_1 = l - k \mid X_0 = j)\\
&= \sum_{k = m + 2}^∞ \sum_{l = m + 2}^∞ P(A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \mid X_0 = j) P(τ_1 = l \mid X_0 = j)\\
&= \left( \sum_{k = m + 2}^∞ P(A_k \cap \{τ_n = k\} \mid X_0 = j) \right) \left( \sum_{l = m + 2}^∞ P(τ_1 = l \mid X_0 = j) \right)\\
&= P(τ_1 < ∞, \cdots, τ_n < ∞) P(τ_1 < ∞ \mid X_0 = j)\\
&= P(τ_1 < ∞, \cdots, τ_n < ∞) = 1.
\end{align*}
End of induction.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I'd like to note that in our course we didn't see what you called "strong Markov property" (or if we did, not by this name). Also, what are $E_j$, $I$ and $\mathscr F$ in your notation? Thanks.

Comment: So is $E_j$ the expectation with respect to the probability $\mathbb P_j$? I know what an indicator function is but we never saw filtrations too so I really don't know what that is... it makes me want to choke my teacher ahah

Comment: I massively appreciate your effort! I'm trying to understand few things: does $\tau_n$ represent the time of the $n$-th visit after the time $m+1$? And does $A_k$ represent the fact of "having the first $n-1$ visits within the time $k-m-1$"? (My intuition would suggest that it should be "within the time $k-1$ since $k\geq m+2$). Thanks again!

Comment: $τ_n$ is the next visit to $j$ after $m+1$ steps after $τ_{n-1}$, and $A_k$ is indeed what you mean before the parentheses. Although $τ_1$ might be forced to take negative values on the event $A_k$, it doesn't matter since the event would by an empty set then.

Comment: So my idea that $A_k$ should be $A_k = \{τ_1 < k - 1, \cdots, τ_{n - 1} < k - 1\}$ for $k \geqslant m + 2$ is wrong? Cause if I assume yours is correct then picking $k = m+2$ (first possible value) would give me $A_{m+2} = \{τ_1 < 1, \cdots, τ_{n - 1} < 1\} = \emptyset$ cause there aren't even $n-1$ different times before time 1.

Comment: @Bafforasta Your reasoning on $A_{m+2}=\varnothing$ is exactly correct, but such details can be dismissed in the summation since $P(\varnothing)=0$.

Comment: which property are you using to go from line two to three from the block after the (1)? If I call $A= \{ A:k \cap \tau_n = k \cap X_k =  j\}, B = \{ \tau_{n+1} = \ell\}$ and $C = \{X_0 = j\}$ that would be $\mathbb P(A \cap B | C) = \mathbb P(A|C)\mathbb P(B|A)$ but I don't recognize this as a general conditional probabilities property.

Comment: Are you just using the fact that $\mathbb P(A\cap B|C)=\mathbb P(A|C)\mathbb P(B|A\cap C)$ along with the Markov property for that one? This is the last doubt I have

Comment: If you can, please confirm I got it correctly, then I'm going to assign the bounty :)

Comment: I assigned the bounty, thanks. Just to confirm that I got it right, you use Markov property to turn $\mathbb P( A \cap B | C) $ from $\mathbb P(A|C)\mathbb P(B|A\cap C)$ to $\mathbb P(A|C)\mathbb P(B|A)$?

Comment: @Bafforasta Yes. Actually I skipped a small step there, and to write it out completely it needs the Bayes' formula to expand the event $A_k\cap\{τ_n=k\}\cap\{X_n=j\}$ as the union of events in the form $\{X_1=\cdots,\cdots,X_n=\cdots\}$. But intuitively, this is easy to understand since the Markov property is just saying that the conditional expectation given the history up to the current moment is equal to that given the current moment only.

Comment: Got it, thanks, you're a life saver :)

Comment: @Bafforasta You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The point of the third equality is that if you a.s. return once, then you a.s. return infinitely many times, because of the Markov property. This equality would *not* be true if the probability to return once were merely positive and not 1.

Comment: @lan: I'm aware that "a path starts in $j$ and it a.c. visits $j$ at least once $\iff$ a path starts in $j$ and it a.c. visits $j$  infinitely many times" but I had no clue about the fact that if you a.c visit $j$ once (assuming that the starting state can be any) then you a.c. visit it infinitely many times. Why is that?

Comment: @Bafforasta I didn't say that if you a.s. visit once then you a.s. visit infinitely many times. I said if you a.s. *return* once then you a.s. *return* infinitely many times. And this is simple, because once you have returned, you have another independent chance to return again, which you will do with the same probability (1) again. In general it is not true that if you a.s. visit once then you a.s. visit infinitely many times. This will fail when the starting state and $j$ are both transient (which must necessarily happen together since transience is a class property).